# Como exportar un plugin en NetBeans para importarlo en otro PC

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Como la pregunta lo dice, tengo en un PC un plugin instalado en NetBeans, quisiera saber si se puede exportar para instalarlo en un NetBeans de otro PC.

Comment: En este caso lo mejor es volverlo a instalar en el NetBeans de la otra pc :)

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta: No es posible.

Respuesta larga:

No es posible porque no hay una lista exacta de los archivos que se descomprimen del nbm, pero aún así, si sabes exactamente los archivos esenciales que componen un plugin puedes copiarlos y pegarlos en la misma carpeta en otra instalación de netbeans con posibilidades variantes de que corra sin errores y realice la misma funcionalidad.

Yo lo he hecho varias veces pero en versiones muy antiguas de netbeans, debido a plugins que fueorn descontinuados y/o tenían errores en versiones posteriores como es le caso del plugin de [jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby) y del plugin de [itext](/questions/tagged/itext).

Suponiendo que los archivos del plugin sean fáciles de hallar y que estés dispuesto a arruinar tu ide e invertirle mucho tiempo el proceso es el siguiente:

1. Ve a la carpeta local de instalación de módulos de tu netbeans, puede variar en cada sistema operativo, en los linux originalmente estaba en `$HOME/.netbeans/VERSION/modules/` y `$HOME/.netbeans/VERSION/config/Modules/` ( y no sé si haya cambiado desde ese entonces ), en mi windows usando [netbeans-9](/questions/tagged/netbeans-9) en mi [windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10) halle las rutas equivalentes en `C:\Users\TUNOMBREDEUSUARIO\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\9.0\modules` y `C:\Users\TUNOMBREDEUSUARIO\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\9.0\modules\ext`
2. Copia los archivos de tu plugin
3. Pega en la carpta equivalente en la otra instalaicón de netbeans

Ejemplo:

Para el plugin nb-spring boot plugin, en la primera carpeta está el archivo `com-github-alexfalappa-nb-springboot-plugin.jar` y en la carpeta ext se encuentra una carpeta que se llama `com.github.alexfalappa.nb-springboot-plugin`.

Puedes usar el mismo procedimiento para agregar librerías que falten en tus plugins, pero deben de cumplir con la [especificación osgi](https://www.osgi.org/developer/where-to-start/).

Adicionalmente te dejo [un tutorial viejito en inglés de como hacerlo](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2008/05/copy-plugins-between-netbeans.html).